# Getting an MP3 to play inside while looping

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, mp3

I'm fairly new to Python, but here goes: I'm designing a code that measures something inside a while loop every 8 seconds, and according to that measure a music plays.
It should go something like this:

```
previous_state = 0
while loop_var:
    #measure something here
    state = measure_Result
    if previous_state != state:
         #change music
    else: #continue to play the music until state changes
```

Any idea on how I could do this? The music should continue to play until the state changes, and when it changes another music should start playing.

I tried using `pyglet` but I kept getting an error that stopped my loop. I also looking into threading but it seems a bit out of my comfort zone in Python. The error was this one:

> Unexpected error loading library avbin: [Error 1114]

Comment: Try using the [`pygame`](http://www.pygame.org) module, it has [functions](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) to start and stop playing MP3s.

Comment: I did end up using pygame instead of pyglet :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

From a design standpoint, you probably want your music playing service on a separate thread that is notified when the state of your application changes. I'm not sure what your error means but it probably from using pyglet in a context that it was not designed for.

Threading in python isn't too bad and there are plenty of tutorials available.

Comment: Thank you. I looked up threading and used the pygame module as martineau suggested and was able to solve my problem :)